# Setting up GRPC service in AWS ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, grpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I tried setting up the GRPC server  with ALB, I have done all the setup [here](https://exampleloadbalancer.com/albgrpc_demo.html), and my target groups as healthy But when I hit the service with the GRPC client it fails . below is the GRPC client log

```
[ec2-user@ greeter_client]$ GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL=info 
GREETER_ENDPOINT=testgrpc-<>.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443 INSECURE=1  go 
run main.go
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] parsed scheme: ""
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc:{[{testgrpc-<>.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Subchannel picks a new address "testgrpc-<>.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:443" to connect
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Subchannel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
INFO: 2022/05/08 20:43:46 [core] Channel Connectivity change to TRANSIENT_FAILURE
2022/05/08 20:43:46 could not greet: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection closed
```

[image: Target Group is healthy]

[image: routing rule]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was certificate used in the https listener was wrong, so  did following to make it work

1. moved my nameserver to r53
2. created public certificate in acm
3. used certificate in the https listener